# Content inside iframe match width of parent div

Tags: iframe, webforms, responsive-design

I have a responsive website that changes style sheets depending on browser width. I have a webform embeded through an iframe. The webform it's self is also responsive. Is there anyway to have the webform width reflect the parent div width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iframe { position: relative; width: 100% }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I feel really stupid the solution was so simple. :-)